# GenericArguments[0], TestClass, on MyGeneric1[T] violates the constraint of type parameter 'T'

Tags: c#, generics

I'm trying to create a generic controller that extends ODataController by following this blog post. https://blog.scottlogic.com/2015/12/01/generalizing-odata.html But I'm currently getting a Type error as described in the title.

I've tried using a basic class that doesn't have entity framework annotations. Also built in class types.

GenericController.cs

```
public class GenericController<T> : ODataController where T: class, IIndexedModel
{
  ...
}
```

MyControllerSelector.cs

```
public class MyControllerSelector : IHttpControllerSelector
{
    private IDictionary<string, HttpControllerDescriptor> _controllerMappings;

    public EntityControllerSelector(
        HttpConfiguration config, IEnumerable<EntitySetConfiguration> entitySets)
    {
        _controllerMappings = GenerateMappings(config, entitySets);
    }

    public IDictionary<string, HttpControllerDescriptor> GenerateMappings(
        HttpConfiguration config, IEnumerable<EntitySetConfiguration> entitySets)
    {
        IDictionary<string, HttpControllerDescriptor> dictionary =
            new Dictionary<string, HttpControllerDescriptor>();

        foreach (EntitySetConfiguration set in entitySets)
        {
             // !!! This throws the type exception !!!
            var genericControllerDescription =
               new HttpControllerDescriptor(config, set.Name,
                   typeof(GenericController<>).MakeGenericType(set.ClrType));

            dictionary.Add(set.Name, genericControllerDescription);
        }

        return dictionary;
    }

    public HttpControllerDescriptor SelectController(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        var path = request.RequestUri.LocalPath.Split('/', '(');
        return _controllerMappings[path[1]];
    }

    public IDictionary<string, HttpControllerDescriptor> GetControllerMapping()
    {
        return _controllerMappings;
    }
}
```

Edit for more info:
TestClass.cs

```
public class TestClass :IIndexedModel {
    public int Id {get; set;}
}
```

IndexModel.cs

```
public interface IIndexedModel {
    int Id { get; set;}
}
```

Instead of set.ClrType I've tried hardcoding different classes in and they all throw the same exception.

> System.ArgumentException: 'GenericArguments[0], '...TestClass', on '...GenericController`1[T]' violates the constraint of type 'T'.'

Inner Exception

> TypeLoadException: GenericArguments[0], '...TestClass', on '...GenericController`1[T]' violates the constraint of type parameter 'T'.

Comment: `where T: class, IndexedModel`

Comment: `T` must be a class deriving from `IndexedModel` or be `IndexedModel` itself.

Comment: Added my TestClass and IndexedModel for more clarification. IndexedModel is an interface that my TestClass implements.

Comment: If it is an interface the correct naming would be `IIndexedModel` and `T` must be a class implementing it. See [C# Coding Standards and Naming Conventions](https://github.com/ktaranov/naming-convention/blob/master/C%23%20Coding%20Standards%20and%20Naming%20Conventions.md#c-coding-standards-and-naming-conventions) Point 12.

Comment: Just renamed it, but have the same error. I'll update my posted code.

Comment: Does it not work with `typeof(GenericController<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(IIndexedModel)));` ? Difficult to tell you, because we have no idea what `set.ClrType` is.

Comment: It doesn't, I just got the same constraint error. System.ArgumentException: 'GenericArguments[0], '...IIndexedModel', on '...GenericController`1[T]' violates the constraint of type 'T'.' The class constraint should just ensure it's a reference type and it is so I'm not sure what other constraints its referring to.

Comment: That's fair, I've also been hardcoding with "typeof(TestClass)" in place of set.ClrType but same error as well. Definitely bizarre.

Comment: There's a piece of code in my GenericController that uses the ID field which is why I say it has to implement that interface. When I commented out that snippet and removed the interface constraint then I didn't get the error. So the constraint violation is due to the interface somehow.

Comment: Does `TestClass` implement `IIndexedModel`? Are you sure `IIndexedModel` is the same type as in the constraint? (It could be a type in a different namespace with the same name).

Comment: Omg, I think this was it. Somehow I had an interface where the filename was IGlobal but the interface inside was called IIndexedModel for some reason. The TestClass was implementing the wrong one.

Comment: If you want to make that the answer I'll verify it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type `T` you pass to

```
typeof(GenericController<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(T))
```

must be a class implementing `IIndexedModel` according to the constraint `where T : class, IIndexedModel`.

Make sure `IIndexedModel` is the same `IIndexedModel` as mentioned in the type constraint. It could be a type with the same name but reside in another namespace or assembly.

Comment: Legends those that put this answer! Just inherited some super old code and was adding a repository. Was getting this error but didnt notice that in this isntance the IRepository<T> was sending the only model in the system than didnt use the base entity interface!!!   Thank you!!!